# unique client Reference id automatic generation Asp.net | Vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web

My friends and I have started creating an e-commerce website using asp.net (vb.net). We are newbies and don't know much about it.

Can anybody show me how we can automatically generate unique reference id for each client who is purchasing the product from the website?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways and methods, but you can use the following command:

```
Dim user_id As Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
```

That will generate a unique Id for you.

You can also generate the new id automatically in your database table. Just make sure to create column with data type `uniqueidentefier`  and assign it a `default` value property `newid()`

Answer (score 0):

You can generate unique id's in database table by providing a column which will have a primary key or unique key assigned to it.and you can set auto increment property of that particular column on so it will increment automatically for each new customer entry.
You can also search the web in the mean time for better approach